# Create or reuse Apple distribution certificate?

Tags: ios, certificate, app-store

When i join team in app store should I create new Apple distribution certificate or use old one which has been created by previous developer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you have the private key that the original distribution certificate was created with, you'll need to create a new distribution cert in order to sign your App Store submission builds. If you have that private key, it's up to you, but there's no reason to change it. (Presumably, the previous developer's access has been removed from the developer portal and they can't do rogue submissions.)

Changing the distribution certificate won't affect anything already on the App Store, but it will invalidate distribution builds that haven't been released yet, and you'll need to regenerate them. If you have a CI pipeline, it may also cause your pipeline to fail until you update your build machine certificates.

One thing I'd caution you about is if you have an Apple Enterprise account. Changing the distribution cert on an enterprise development account will invalidate any enterprise app builds already using it, and you'll have to regenerate them. That could cause a significant disruption if your company has enterprise apps in use.

Comment: So to summarize it's better to ask for private key and use same certificate, wright?

Comment: That would likely be the least disruptive approach, but you might as well look in the portal and see when the current certificate expires. If it's relatively soon, you're going to have to regenerate it then anyway. The biggest thing is to understand the potential impact of regenerating the distribution certificate and planning around that.